# Acceptable scores on a survey

Tags: dataset, survey

I want to know what per cent is acceptable in a training survey?  If we get scores of 77% satisfaction of our materials is that acceptable, good, poor?

Comment: Too little context. How many respondents were there in the survey? How many of them did not fill in the questionnaires? How was the satisfaction question worded? Have you had surveys during previous training cycles? How do you plan to cope with polite insincerity in responses? What is your loss function? Did you check the questionnaire with professional psychologists before conducting the survey? Etc. etc.

Comment: @DeerHunter asks good questions. Also, what were the answer choices? What is your goal? Who are the people taking the survey? What were they being trained for?

Answer (score 3):

Scores such as these can never be compared against absolute standards, only relative standards.  Normally you have two choices: the same question that has been asked of people to rate satisfaction of other products; or the same question for your product, asked at a different time.

So 77% is good if you have improved from 60%, or all your competitors get 60% (assuming that the statistical margin of error is small enough that you are confident this reflects a real difference, not just the accidents of sampling).  And it is bad if you used to get 90%, or your competitors all get 90%.  There's no more magic to it than that.